# Determining observer's position based on azimuth and elevation of observed object

Tags: nasa, space-geometry

It is possible to generate Ephemeris through the web-interface of JPL's Horizon system based on observer's location. Unfortunately I don't know the formula that is used to do that with a high precision but I'd like to reverse this action.

[image]

Having Azimuth and Elevation of The Moon at a certain date and time, I'd like to know the observer's location. Where do I even start?

Comment: I'm not sure if Horizons has any "event detection" capability, but if you would like an answer with a simple Python program to do this, the [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) package is perfect for this. Would that be helpful? If the object was a star or something fixed on the celestial sphere, a simple equation-based answer would be easy, but the Moon's orbit is inclined and eccentric so equations for a reverse-lookup will be pretty messy.